Share Python packages installed with --user with all users
We have a bunch of Python 3.11 packages installed as rpms in all our hosts running SuSE Linux Enterprise (> 100 machines). Sometimes we need additional packages that are not available in any SuSE repository or we need newer versions of installed packages. But we don't want to touch the installed SuSE rpms to avoid dependency problems among any SuSE packages.
So we plan to install those packages with pip to e.g. /opt/ourpython/. To avoid accidentally removing or altering things in /usr/lib/.../site-packages we plan to call pip as some user whose account is only used for software installation purposes.
We would set PYTHONUSERBASE=/opt/ourpython/3.11/ and then call pip with --user. After installing/removing/upgrading packages like that on one special hosts, we would pack /opt/ourpython/ into our own rpm package and distribute that to all hosts, so that the Python packages are available for all users automatically when they call /usr/bin/python3.11. We include that /opt path with a .pth file in the /usr/lib/.../site-packages path so that it gets added automatically.
That works fine in our tests, but we wonder if it could happen that packages installed with --user have some references to that special username or user environment that might cause problems when packages from /opt/ourpython are used by other users. Could that happen?

There are no drawbacks on packages installed with --user as you propose: as far as the concerns you had presented, your plan is fine.
You might just check pip docs  (pip install --help) - for pip install --prefix, so you won´t need to use --user or modify env var for setting a special package.
Also, once upon  a time, things like /opt/ourpython could be distributed as an NFS mount instead of creating an RPM, across an homogeneous environment - but that, of course, has a lot of implications.

Thanks a lot! We tried --prefix at first, but that must be called as user and then we get problems when trying to install a newer version of a package existing in /usr because pip tries to uninstall the old package and fails, of course, so we always get error messages etc. Using --ignore-installed would solve that, but that causes other problems if an old version in /usr and a newer in /opt exists and the one in /opt should be upgraded. --user indeed solves these problems as it never even tries to mangle with /usr.
